# How i can create a SASS map from variables?

Tags: sass

I have some SASS variables:

```
$one: 'one';
$two: 'two';
$three: 'three';
```

How I can create from those variables this map?

```
$list: (
    one: one,
    two: two,
    three: three
);
```

Comment: Why can't you write it as you did there?

Comment: I need those variables and a map that have a correlation, without then need to change the map every time I change a variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "change a variable"? Can you give an example of what you are expecting?

Comment: If I add a variable like $four: 'four' it's automatically added to the map.

Comment: It is not possible, SASS can't guess what variable you want in the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need 2 separate files. One file containing your variables. This will create a namespace (module) with those variables in it. In the second file we can then extract all those variables out of your module using sass' build in 'meta' module, and use it to fill up the map.

More info on sass documentation page: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/meta/#module-variables

File: '_variables.scss'

```
$one: 'one';
$two: 'two';
$three: 'three';
```

File: '_variables-mapped.scss'

```
@use "sass:meta";
@use "sass:map";
@use "./variables" as myVariablesAlias;

$mapName: ()

@each $name, $value in meta.module-variables("myVariablesAlias") {
    $mapName: map.merge($mapName, ($name: $value));
}

@debug $mapName; // outputs (one: 'one', two: 'two', three: 'three')
```

EDIT: after rereading the documentation myself, you can probably even do it without the loop. Note, i haven't tested that myself

```
$mapName: meta.module-variables("myVariablesAlias")
```